# Unit-testing a boost::python library in python

Tags: python, c++, unit-testing, boost, out-of-source

So I have a shared library created with boost::python (C++). 
For the C++ functions inside I have unit-tests that check that they are working.
Now I would like to use unit-test to see if I implemented the python interface correctly.
For this I thought about using using the python package `unittest`.

Now my Folder setup is roughly:

```
project
  |
   -- C++ source (library and boost::python stuff)
  |
   -- build (here the shared library is located)
  |
   -- Test (here I have the python classes that should test the interface)
```

The test folder has some subfolders that mirror the structure of the python interface, containing lots of small python modules testing the different aspects of the library.

So the **question** now:

> How do I `import` the shared library into the test?

What I tried so far was in my `test_main.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'../build')
```

But this does not help for the modules inside the test folder. And anyways hardcoding this path into the test-code seems to be hackish. I also don't want to install an untested library just to figure out the tests failed to then uninstall it again.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is run the tests while you are in the root directory in your case `project`. You can do `python Test/test_name.py`. Make sure your build library has a `__init__.py` file

The only change to the test is you'd have

```
from build import blah #blah is the component you testing
#test code here
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work on my machine. When I am in the root directory and open a python shell and type: `import build.blah` it works. But If I call `python Test/my_test.py` with `import build.blah` in this file, it does not work.

Comment: ... your test.py should have `from build.blah import blah`

Comment: That is not the issue (I tried your suggestion). It complains that "no module named build". I think in `Test/my_test.py` it still looks relative to `Test` even though it is called from the parent folder.

Comment: If you run python with `PYTHONPATH=.${PYTHONPATH:+:}$PYTHONPATH python Test/test_name.py` this will work. Basically the same as your `sys.path` stuff, but at least you moved it outside and kept your Python tidier. You may have to meddle with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also, if your code want to load natively compiled modules.

Comment: @clacke This seems to work. Only issue now (but I forgot to mention it in the question) is that if I have different build-configurations (debug/release) as subfolders, the configuration is hardcoded in the import statement. But for now I will stick with your suggestion until I feel it becomes too cluttered.

Comment: You probably want to move that out of the import statement and into the `*PATH` variables, to be handled by some build / test script.

Comment: @MrZ I recommend you `pip install nose` and run `nosetests Test/` from root of app.